# Taylor series of function e^x

Tags: c, taylor-series

Given a number x. You need to calculate sum of Taylor Series of e^x.

> e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...

Calculate sum until a general number is lower or equal to 10^(-9).

Down below is my solution but it is wrong for x<0 numbers. Do you have any idea how to fix this to work for negative numbers.

```
    int x,i,n;
    long long fact; //fact needs to be double
    double sum=0,k=1;
    scanf("%d",&x);
            i=0; sum=0; k=1;
                while (fabs(k)>=1.0E-9) {
                    fact=1;
                    for (int j=1;j<=i;++j)
                        fact*=j;
                    k=pow(x,i)/fact;
                    sum+=k;
                    ++i;
                }
    printf("%lf\n",sum);
```

Comment: what types are those variables... if you don't give us enough to compile, you haven't given us enough to debug

Comment: Sorry, I just added.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot that. But result is wrong again. For examle if x=-2 output is 0.33333, it needs to be 0.13533, for x=-4 sum=0.192240 it needs to be 0.018316 etc...

Comment: Are you using namespace std? Did you include cmath or math.h? It would also be good if you explicitly converted your data types

Comment: fabs, floating point abs, my bad.

Comment: @user3728501: it is C code not C++ code

Comment: https://ideone.com/PyGPO6

Comment: I just changed type of fact to double, and it works

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Point still stands - don't use a namespace and only include math.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fact needs to be double, it can not be long long because of divides.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `pow` function for raising a (possibly negative) number to an integer power. Instead use repeated multiplication as you do to compute the factorial.

Notice also that you could store the last computed values of $n!$ and $x^k$ to obtain $(n+1)!$ and $x^{k+1}$ with a single multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your factorial computation overflows and becomes garbage.
After that your `ith` term doesn't decrease anymore and produce completely wrong results.

After 20 iterations a 64 bits number cannot contains the value of `20!`. See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=21%21%2F2%5E64

If `x^n/n!` is not inferior to your threshold (`1e-9`) when `n=20` then your computation of `n!` will overflow even a 64 bits integer. When that happens you will get the value of `n!` modulo `2^63` (I simplify because you didn't use an unsigned integer and you will get random negative value instead but the principle remains). These values may be very low instead of being very high. And this will cause your `x^n/n!` to become greater instead of smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure, Can you explain better. I found that problem is in type of fact, when I changed fact to double it works good for small number (this is what  I needed). I don't know why. I would ask you to better explain your answer because it seems interesting, I agree that the solution has an overflow, but nothing significant.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you for explanation. But I can not use unsigned int because x can be negative.

Comment: @dreamer Using `unsigned` will not change the problem. It will just produce exact modulos (mod 2^63) instead of two's complement interpretation of the modulo. But the problem will remain. If this explanation helped you, don't forget to upvote.